# GET data from database to Modal in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

this file
**serivces.html** has the code used to generate card elements with different id from thedb

```
{% block content%}
<div class="container-fluid p-lg-5  d-flex justify-content-lg-around   flex-wrap ">
  {% for package in packages %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; ">
    <div>

      <img class="cardimg" src="{% static '/images/genomic lab final logo1 ( RGB ).png'%}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="text-center">{{package.package_name}}  <span class="checkup text-center">Checkup</span></h3>

      <button type="button" class="modalbtn btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#cardModal">
        more details
       </button>
    </div>
  </div>

 

  
  {% endfor%}
</div>


<<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade content-data" id="cardModal"  data-url="{%url 'Services_data'%}"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{details.pkg_name}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <H4>{{details.content}}</H4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is the **view.py**
contain

```
def services(request):

    packages = Packages.objects.all()
    context = {'packages':packages}

    return render(request, 'base/Services.html',context)

class AjaxHandlerView(View):
    def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            details = Details.object.all()
            details_serializers = serializers.serializer('json',details)
            return JsonResponse(details_serializers,safe=False)
        return JsonResponse({'message':'Errrorr'})
```

and this is the **base.js** contain the ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modalbtn").on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'Services_data' %}",
        type:'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(){
          $('#cardModal').modal("show");

        },
        error:function()
          {console.log('Errorrrr');
        }
        
        });
  
      });

   
      });
```

Basically, this code generates cards with different id
and when click on the more details button inside a specific card
a modal 'popup' should be shown containing details regarding the card

but I have nothing inside the popup
any suggestions ??

Comment: Your success function discards the server's reply, it just shows the empty popup. You need to add a parameter to the function and insert its HTML string into your popup first `success: function (html) { $('#cardModal').html(html).modal("show") }` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing appears is that your AJAX request doesn't change your modal section and the modal section doesn't contain any information to begin with because the `details` object is provided by your AJAX-related view, not the services view that creates it.

I would suggest a few fixes:

1. Make your javascript code update the modal HTML, like so:

```
   success: function(data) {
       $('#cardModal').HTML();
       $('#cardModal').modal("show");
    }
```

2. Move your inner modal HTML to a separate template file called 'detail-modal.html' (or something similar), but keep the main `#cardModal` container in your existing template.
3. Instead of using a serializer and JSON in your AJAX class view, use a function view that renders the new modal template, the context being your selected detail object

Finally, your naming convention has a plural `Details` objects, you should name it as a singular `Detail`. There also doesn't seem to be a connection between `Package` and `Details`, presumably you want some sort of relationship - that would help you a lot.